# spring integration jdbc inbound poller is failing on update query with invalid column type

Tags: spring-integration

We are using following config for polling db table to pick rows and as soon as those rows are picked we want to update it status to something else so it does not picked up again in next poll. Here is config which is failing on update query with error message

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
    auto-startup="true" channel="pollingChannel"
    query="$select id,status from test_table where status='ready'"
    data-source="dataSource"
    id="pollingChannelAdapter"
    row-mapper="testRowMapper"
    update="update test_table set status='picked' where id in (:id)"
    update-per-row="true"
    >

    <int:poller default="false" id="poller" max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the fix. I have to use proper property which is defined in value object as i was parsing select query response using row mapper to some value object which did not had property named "id". Once i changed to correct one, it started working fine.